# How is experience distributed between my party members?

Tags: legend-of-grimrock

I've got two fighters on the front line, with a rogue and mage at the back.

The fighters both leveled up first, but I'm now a few floors down and I've noticed that my mage is now in the lead on experience, the fighters are still effectively equal, and the rogue is a little bit behind.

The differences between the characters aren't significant yet (they're all the same level still), but I'm wondering if I can and should be trying to prevent this from diverging too far.

Essentially, **how is experience distributed between my party members?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From my experience, if a character damages a monster, he will gain full amount of experience when that monster is killed (e.g. 90XP for skeleton), but if he is not involved in killing monster, he will gain half of experience (e.g. 45XP for skeleton). Dead characters gain no experience.

For monster groups, each monster kill is counted as killing single monster.

And that is probably what makes your party having different XP:

- There are more groups in lower levels.
- Since most of (or even all) spells affect all monsters in group, your mage started gaining full XP from all monsters.
- When fighting group of monsters, fighters will first hit monsters in front of them (left fighter will hit left monster) and then hit monsters at the other side (left fighter will hit right monster if left monster is dead) and when first row is finished they will get to the back row.
- I presume you are using rogue for ranged attack, and in that case he will only hit monsters in front of him (if rogue is to the left, he will, in most cases, hit only left monsters, and when they die he will just miss right side monsters).

**Edit:** And as HenryHey [said](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/77381/1485), they all get XP for finding secrets.

Comment: This sounds very plausible, and the XP / half-XP split should be easy to test - I'll try killing some stuff while watching the numbers this evening - although it doesn't seem to tie up with what HenryHey is saying (with respect to fighters getting better XP from melee, rogues from ranged, etc).

Comment: I've also found that dead players don't get xp, or at least I think that is was has happened when different characters lvl up differently, though the half xp thing is probably another reason

Comment: @DMA57361: Well I've never tested fighter/ranged or mage/mele or mage/ranged, but I have one rogue in front line doing damage only with dager and he gets full XP (which would still support both theories, since rogues can specialize in daggers).

Comment: @Holger: I completely forgot about dead members of party. I'll have to check and update my post. Thanks :)

Comment: I checked. Dead characters gain no experience.

Comment: Well, having had a play, this all seems to be correct. +1 and ticked, thanks! :)

Comment: BTW, rouge is makeup, a _rogue_ is the guy with a dagger.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Grimrock Wiki](http://grimrockwiki.net/):

> They can be obtained
> in various ways, primarily based on which class the prisoner belongs
> to:
>
> - Fighters gain xp primarily by damaging opponents with melee
>   attacks
> - Rogues gain xp primarily by damaging opponents with ranged
>   attacks
> - Mages gain xp primarily by casting spells and using magic
>   items
> - The whole party gains xp by solving puzzles & finding secrets.

Answer (score 1):

To fix that, you have to use the Spirit Mirror Pendant, which increases the rate at which the wearer gains experience.  When some of your team members level up slow, tell them to equip the necklaces.

Answer (score 0):

The other important things to add is, they have to do damage to get the full XP. Just because your Mage took some swings at the monster and missed 3 times, does not qualify him for the full XP. They must do some damage to it.

Answer (score 0):

I have two things to add to this...

1. To the best of my knowledge, there is *no experience* gained for finding secrets or solving puzzles in the main game; experience comes from combat *only*. (Some mods give experience for other things.)
2. They do not, strictly speaking, have to do damage in order to qualify for full experience. They do, however, need to hit. So, a miss doesn't qualify them for full XP, but a hit of 0 damage does. There may be an exception for the monsters that have a damage-absorbing shield. I haven't tested this one, but I've heard that you don't qualify for full XP if your attack was absorbed by the shield.